# Converting factor into time type

Tags: r, date

Let I have the below data frame:

```
data<-structure(list(date = structure(c(9996, 9996, 9996, 9996, 9996, 
                                  9996, 9996, 9996, 9996, 9996), class = "Date"), time = structure(61:70, .Label = c("09:30", 
                                                                                                                     "09:31", "09:32", "09:33", "09:34", "09:35", "09:36", "09:37", 
                                                                                                                     "09:38", "09:39", "09:40", "09:41", "09:42", "09:43", "09:44", 
                                                                                                                     "09:45", "09:46", "09:47", "09:48", "09:49", "09:50", "09:51", 
                                                                                                                     "09:52", "09:53", "09:54", "09:55", "09:56", "09:57", "09:58", 
                                                                                                                     "09:59", "10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03", "10:04", "10:05", 
                                                                                                                     "10:06", "10:07", "10:08", "10:09", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", 
                                                                                                                     "10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "10:16", "10:17", "10:18", "10:19", 
                                                                                                                     "10:20", "10:21", "10:22", "10:23", "10:24", "10:25", "10:26", 
                                                                                                                     "10:27", "10:28", "10:29", "10:30", "10:31", "10:32", "10:33", 
                                                                                                                     "10:34", "10:35", "10:36", "10:37", "10:38", "10:39", "10:40", 
                                                                                                                     "10:41", "10:42", "10:43", "10:44", "10:45", "10:46", "10:47", 
                                                                                                                     "10:48", "10:49", "10:50", "10:51", "10:52", "10:53", "10:54", 
                                                                                                                     "10:55", "10:56", "10:57", "10:58", "10:59", "11:00", "11:01", 
                                                                                                                     "11:02", "11:03", "11:04", "11:05", "11:06", "11:07", "11:08", 
                                                                                                                     "11:09", "11:10", "11:11", "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", 
                                                                                                                     "11:16", "11:17", "11:18", "11:19", "11:20", "11:21", "11:22", 
                                                                                                                     "11:23", "11:24", "11:25", "11:26", "11:27", "11:28", "11:29", 
                                                                                                                     "11:30", "11:31", "11:32", "11:33", "11:34", "11:35", "11:36", 
                                                                                                                     "11:37", "11:38", "11:39", "11:40", "11:41", "11:42", "11:43", 
                                                                                                                     "11:44", "11:45", "11:46", "11:47", "11:48", "11:49", "11:50", 
                                                                                                                     "11:51", "11:52", "11:53", "11:54", "11:55", "11:56", "11:57", 
                                                                                                                     "11:58", "11:59", "12:00", "12:01", "12:02", "12:03", "12:04", 
                                                                                                                     "12:05", "12:06", "12:07", "12:08", "12:09", "12:10", "12:11", 
                                                                                                                     "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "12:16", "12:17", "12:18", 
                                                                                                                     "12:19", "12:20", "12:21", "12:22", "12:23", "12:24", "12:25", 
                                                                                                                     "12:26", "12:27", "12:28", "12:29", "12:30", "12:31", "12:32", 
                                                                                                                     "12:33", "12:34", "12:35", "12:36", "12:37", "12:38", "12:39", 
                                                                                                                     "12:40", "12:41", "12:42", "12:43", "12:44", "12:45", "12:46", 
                                                                                                                     "12:47", "12:48", "12:49", "12:50", "12:51", "12:52", "12:53", 
                                                                                                                     "12:54", "12:55", "12:56", "12:57", "12:58", "12:59", "13:00", 
                                                                                                                     "13:01", "13:02", "13:03", "13:04", "13:05", "13:06", "13:07", 
                                                                                                                     "13:08", "13:09", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", 
                                                                                                                     "13:15", "13:16", "13:17", "13:18", "13:19", "13:20", "13:21", 
                                                                                                                     "13:22", "13:23", "13:24", "13:25", "13:26", "13:27", "13:28", 
                                                                                                                     "13:29", "13:30", "13:31", "13:32", "13:33", "13:34", "13:35", 
                                                                                                                     "13:36", "13:37", "13:38", "13:39", "13:40", "13:41", "13:42", 
                                                                                                                     "13:43", "13:44", "13:45", "13:46", "13:47", "13:48", "13:49", 
                                                                                                                     "13:50", "13:51", "13:52", "13:53", "13:54", "13:55", "13:56", 
                                                                                                                     "13:57", "13:58", "13:59", "14:00", "14:01", "14:02", "14:03", 
                                                                                                                     "14:04", "14:05", "14:06", "14:07", "14:08", "14:09", "14:10", 
                                                                                                                     "14:11", "14:12", "14:13", "14:14", "14:15", "14:16", "14:17", 
                                                                                                                     "14:18", "14:19", "14:20", "14:21", "14:22", "14:23", "14:24", 
                                                                                                                     "14:25", "14:26", "14:27", "14:28", "14:29", "14:30", "14:31", 
                                                                                                                     "14:32", "14:33", "14:34", "14:35", "14:36", "14:37", "14:38", 
                                                                                                                     "14:39", "14:40", "14:41", "14:42", "14:43", "14:44", "14:45", 
                                                                                                                     "14:46", "14:47", "14:48", "14:49", "14:50", "14:51", "14:52", 
                                                                                                                     "14:53", "14:54", "14:55", "14:56", "14:57", "14:58", "14:59", 
                                                                                                                     "15:00", "15:01", "15:02", "15:03", "15:04", "15:05", "15:06", 
                                                                                                                     "15:07", "15:08", "15:09", "15:10", "15:11", "15:12", "15:13", 
                                                                                                                     "15:14", "15:15", "15:16", "15:17", "15:18", "15:19", "15:20", 
                                                                                                                     "15:21", "15:22", "15:23", "15:24", "15:25", "15:26", "15:27", 
                                                                                                                     "15:28", "15:29", "15:30", "15:31", "15:32", "15:33", "15:34", 
                                                                                                                     "15:35", "15:36", "15:37", "15:38", "15:39", "15:40", "15:41", 
                                                                                                                     "15:42", "15:43", "15:44", "15:45", "15:46", "15:47", "15:48", 
                                                                                                                     "15:49", "15:50", "15:51", "15:52", "15:53", "15:54", "15:55", 
                                                                                                                     "15:56", "15:57", "15:58", "15:59", "16:00"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     10L), class = "data.frame")
```

It as two columns: date and time.

"date" column has no probem. But, "time" column seems as factor. I want to convert it into time format.

I searched some contents about that, but I coudn't manage to convert. I will be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what time of time format you are looking for, but here are two possibilities, one using lubridate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

testdata %>% mutate(datetime=paste(date,time)) %>% mutate(timeformat=lubridate::hm(time)) -> newtestdata

> newtestdata
         date  time         datetime timeformat
1  1997-05-15 10:30 1997-05-15 10:30 10H 30M 0S
2  1997-05-15 10:31 1997-05-15 10:31 10H 31M 0S
3  1997-05-15 10:32 1997-05-15 10:32 10H 32M 0S
4  1997-05-15 10:33 1997-05-15 10:33 10H 33M 0S
5  1997-05-15 10:34 1997-05-15 10:34 10H 34M 0S
6  1997-05-15 10:35 1997-05-15 10:35 10H 35M 0S
7  1997-05-15 10:36 1997-05-15 10:36 10H 36M 0S
8  1997-05-15 10:37 1997-05-15 10:37 10H 37M 0S
9  1997-05-15 10:38 1997-05-15 10:38 10H 38M 0S
10 1997-05-15 10:39 1997-05-15 10:39 10H 39M 0S
```

This gives various formats:

```
> str(newtestdata)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date      : Date, format: "1997-05-15" "1997-05-15" "1997-05-15" "1997-05-15" ...
 $ time      : Factor w/ 391 levels "09:30","09:31",..: 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
 $ datetime  : chr  "1997-05-15 10:30" "1997-05-15 10:31" "1997-05-15 10:32" "1997-05-15 10:33" ...
 $ timeformat:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ .Data : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  .. ..@ hour  : num  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
  .. ..@ minute: num  30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Comment: thanks for your quick return. Is there any other solution without package "dplyr". I have problems installing that package.

Comment: sure, you can just do `lubridate::hm(testdata$time)` and that will do it.